# KendoUI MVC Json - do they work together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am client-server, SQL programmer (RAD guy) and the company decided that we must move to .NET environment. We are examining the platform now.

I studied the MVC4 and the Entities Framework this week and I have read a lot about KendoUI. I was skeptical because most of the examples come with KendoGrid+WebApi. I know awfully little about WebApi but I really liked the Entities thing a lot so I do not think I should give it a chance.

I want to ask some question which may seem naive but the answers will help me a lot

1. Once I create entities from an existing database, can I have the results in Json format and with this to feed a KendoGrid?

   If yes, how? I mean:
2. How I can convert the results in Json inside the Controller?
3. In the transport property of the KendoGrid I should put the URL of the Controller/Action?

   and the most naive one
4. Does Telerik have any thoughts of providing a visual tool to create-configure the kendoGrid? To make it more RAD because now need TOO MUCH coding. Maybe a wizard that you can connect entities with Grid columns, datasource, transport selectors etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you choose the Kendo Entities path, there will be a learning curve though.  No, on question 4.  But let me give you a jump start using the Razor view engine and answer 1, 2, and 3.

First, EF is creating business objects.  You 'should' convert these to Models in MVC.  In this example Person is from EF.  I think of this as flattening because it removes the depth from the object, though it i still available so you could reference something like Person.Titles.Name if your database was setup like that.  You can also drop in DataAnnotations, which just rock.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using Project.Business;

namespace Project.Web.Models
{
    public class PersonModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Created")]
        public System.DateTime StampCreated { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Updated")]
        public System.DateTime StampUpdated { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Enabled")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public PersonModel()
        {}
        public PersonModel(Person person)
        {
            Id = person.Id;
            FirstName = person.FirstName;
            LastName = person.LastName;
            StampCreated = person.StampCreated;
            StampUpdated = person.StampUpdated;
            IsActive = person.IsActive;
        }

        public static IList<PersonModel> FlattenToThis(IList<Person> people)
        {
            return people.Select(person => new PersonModel(person)).ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

Moving along...

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PersonModel>()
    .Name("PersonGrid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(b => b.Id).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(b => b.LastName).EditorTemplateName("_TextBox50");
        columns.Bound(b => b.FirstName).EditorTemplateName("_TextBox50");
        columns.Bound(b => b.StampUpdated);
        columns.Bound(b => b.StampCreated);
        columns.Bound(b => b.IsActive).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' ${ IsActive == true ? checked='checked' : ''} disabled />").Width(60);
            columns.Command(cmd => { cmd.Edit(); cmd.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
        })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Pageable()
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Selectable()
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(a => a.Id);
                model.Field(a => a.StampCreated).Editable(false);
                model.Field(a => a.StampUpdated).Editable(false);
                model.Field(a => a.IsActive).DefaultValue(true);
            })
        .Create(create => create.Action("CreatePerson", "People"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadPeople", "People"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdatePerson", "People"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DestroyPerson", "People"))
        .PageSize(10)
    )
)
```

Those _TextBox50 are EditorTemplates named _TextBox50.cshtml that MUST go either in a subfolder relative to your view or relative to your Shared folder - the folder must be called EditorTemplates.  This one looks like this...

```
@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, string.Empty, new { @class = "k-textbox", @maxlength = "50" })
```

Yes, thats all.  This is a simple example, they can get much more complicated.  Or you don't have to use them initially.

And finally, what I think you are really looking for...

```
public partial class PeopleController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPersonDataProvider _personDataProvider;

    public PeopleController() : this(new PersonDataProvider())
    {}
    public PeopleController(IPersonDataProvider personDataProvider)
    {
        _personDataProvider = personDataProvider;
    }

    public ActionResult Manage()
    {
>>> Left in as teaser, good to apply a special Model to a View to pass goodies ;)
        var model = new PeopleViewModel();
        model.AllQualifications = QualificationModel.FlattenToThis(_qualificationDataProvider.Read());
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreatePerson([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                person = _personDataProvider.Create(person);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, e.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
        var persons = new List<Person> {person};
        DataSourceResult result = PersonModel.FlattenToThis(persons).ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult ReadPeople([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var persons = _personDataProvider.Read(false);
        DataSourceResult result = PersonModel.FlattenToThis(persons).ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdatePerson([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                person = _personDataProvider.Update(person);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, e.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
        var persons = new List<Person>() {person};
        DataSourceResult result = PersonModel.FlattenToThis(persons).ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DestroyPerson([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                person = _personDataProvider.Destroy(person);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "There was an error deleting this record, it may still be in use.");
            }
        }
        var persons = new List<Person>() {person};
        DataSourceResult result = PersonModel.FlattenToThis(persons).ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Notice that, in this case, each method takes the EF Person as a parameter, it would be better to use PersonModel but then I would have to show the opposite of the Flatten.  This works becuase they are practically identical.  If the model was different or you were using a class factory it gets a bit more tricky.

I intentionally showed you all the CRUD operations.  If you don't pass the result back to the grid it will act funny and give you dupicates or not show updates correctly on CREATE and UPDATE.  It is passed back on DELETE to pass the ModelState which would have any errors.

And finally the data provider, so as to leave nothing to the imagination...
(Namespace declaration omited.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Project.Business;

public class PersonDataProvider : ProviderBase, IPersonDataProvider
{
    public Person Create(Person person)
    {
        try
        {
            person.StampCreated = DateTime.Now;
            person.StampUpdated = DateTime.Now;

            Context.People.Attach(person);
            Context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Added;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return person;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public IList<Person> Read(bool showAll)
    {
        try
        {
            return (from q in Context.People
                      orderby q.LastName, q.FirstName, q.StampCreated
                      where (q.IsActive == true || showAll)
                      select q).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }

...

}
```

Note the Interface and ProviderBase inheritance, you have to make those.  Should be simple enough to find examples.

This may seem like a lot of coding, but once you get it down, just copy paste.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you Trey!!! Kendo is THE way to go I guess. I have one last problem that blocks me. When I create Entities from database that use PKs and FKs, I get the "circular reference" error message when I try to Json the data in the Controller and send them to KendoGrid in the View.I have no circular reference in my DB schema relations though! I search, study, test but I cannot overcome it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153325/ef-entities-that-contain-relations-pks-fks-cannot-be-json-ed/14153584#comment19607285_14153584

Comment: @Trey Gramann, is "FlattenToThis" used to prevent circular reference?

Comment: Among other things. It removes the deep structure from the EF generated classes. Typically there is a 1-to-1 mapping between the model and EF class. But in some cases my FlattenToThis takes several object parameters and perform operations to setup the model that may not have a direct correlation to the database, just the presentation. So wondering about business logic? My team moves the generated EF classes into a business project, interfaces, and partials so we can extend without overwrite risk. How? Customized T4 templates. I know, TMI.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can send the JSON back kendo UI using the JsonResult or using the JSON with allow get specified. you can set the url in the transport and specify the json as the type.

About your last question there is no visual tools right now but there are helper methods available for kendo UI